# Can you link text boxes in Illustrator like InDesign?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, text

Can you link text boxes in Illustrator the same way you can in InDesign?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Select the first text box, click the square just above the lower right corner, and then click on the second text box.

Comment: I honestly didn't know Illustrator had this function. But I hope I never have to use it — InDesign is infinitely more adept at handling long passages of text!